# Can Anyone tell me How to delete two elements at same time in java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-arrays

For example:

```
int[] nums = {11,12,13,14,15,16};
int[] position = {1,2};
```

So, here I want to delete multiple elements like for example, I want to remove index 1 and 2 at the same time: when I call the delete method.

```
public int[] delete(int[] source, int[] position) {
    // How do I implement this?
}

//Main Class
public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] newArray = delete(nums, position);

}
```

So, How DO I Solve This????? I have tried many times but I could not map the position and array value. So, it's really difficult to delete two values.

Comment: You can't. May I suggest that in this case, delete position 2 first, then position 1. You may have to sort the position array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a method like this? Java arrays cannot be resized, you must make a new one.

```
public static int[] delete(int[] source, int[] position) {
    Arrays.sort(position);
    int positionIdx = 0;
    int[] newArray = new int[source.length - position.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (positionIdx < position.length && i == position[positionIdx]) {
            positionIdx++;
        } else {
            newArray[i - positionIdx] = source[i];
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    int[] position = {1, 2};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(delete(nums, position)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I want to implement.

Comment: Please explain me what you did with newArray[i-positionIdx]

Comment: @Derslived positionIdx represents the offset (how many elements deleted so far) so we access `newArray[i - positionIdx]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's easier using ArrayList and converting your arrays as Integer instead of the primitive int.

---

1. The first problem here is in `position[]` parameter at `delete` function: you can get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because anyone calling this function can pass a list of positions which cannot have in array num[]

For Example:

the `num[]` array is size 4 and someone passes a position{1,6}, in this case 6th index doesn't exist in num[])

---

2. The second problem is assuring the right index is being removed.

For example, if num{34, 53, 33, 64} and the position{0, 1} representing the index to be deleted, you would expect numbers 34 and 53 to be removed, but as the 0 index is deleted, 53 becomes the 0 index and not the index 1 as before.

So the workarround here is to reverse sort position, so it prevents this problem.

---

Here is an example code just to illustrate the delete function:

```java
Integer num[]... //Using Integer instead of int will be use to remove items using ArrayList

public void delete(Integer[] position){   //position[] being Integer instead of int will be easier to rever sorting
    //
    //Reversing order of position[] to prevent problem 2
    Arrays.sort(position, Collections.reverseOrder());
    //
    ArrayList<Integer> objArrayListMyNumbers = Array.asList(num);
    //
    // Iterate through every element of position
    for(Integer i : position){
        //
        //It's better surround by try and catch, because of the problem 1 (IndexOutOfBoundsException)
        try{
            objArrayListMyNumbers.remove(i);
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStack();
        }
    }
//
    //Gets a new Array with items removed
    num = new Integer(objArrayListMyNumbers.size());
    num = objArrayListMyNumbers.toArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a solution based on filtering streams:

```
static int[] deleteAtPositions(int[] nums, int[] positions) {
    Set<Integer> idx = Arrays.stream(positions).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
                    .filter(i -> !idx.contains(i)) // no need to check for bounds
                    .map(i -> nums[i])
                    .toArray();
}

int[] nums = {11,12,13,14,15,16};
int[] positions = {1,2};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deleteAtPositions(nums, positions)));
```

Output:

```
[11, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: Maybe but, I don't have a concept of filtering stream.